# setVisibility not work after animation set for a view

Tags: android, animation, visibility

After searching some questions like this, I still don't know its detail. Someone says that calling `clearAnimation` before setting visibility works correctly, but for me, it doesn't work sometimes. So, is there anyone who knows why it works or why it doesn't work?

thanks!!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: sorry,I can't get my source code right now. Have you ever use the github open source project "AndroidViewAnimations" for animation? I can't set the visibility(GONE) for the view which has used the YoYo animation.I will post my source code tomorrow.

Comment: YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse).duration(10000).playOn(aq.id(R.id.splash).getView());                                                                                                                I used something like this for a view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    view.clearAnimation();
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
```

Comment: According to StackOverflow rules you should provide a clear explanation on why does your solution work. Please, don't forget to do this next time.